# Error while installing Nitrogen

Tags: erlang, installation, nitrogen

while installing the nitrogen i had the following error. Following install instructions outlined in http://nitrogenproject.com/doc/tutorial.html, I pulled source from GitHub and ran the following command.

```
    msairam@passion:~/nitrogen$ make slim_yaws PROJECT=testproj 

    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/msairam/nitrogen'

    ./rebar get-deps

    ==> rel (get-deps)

    ==> nitrogen (get-deps) 

    ./rebar compile

    ==> rel (compile) 

    ==> nitrogen (compile)

    make[2]: Entering directory '/home/msairam/nitrogen'

    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/msairam/nitrogen'
    ********************************************************************************
   Creating slim release in ../testproj with yaws
    ********************************************************************************

Generating "reltool.config" with merged overlays

...Loading base file: "reltool_base.config"

...Merging Overlay from "reltool_slim.config"

...Writing "reltool.config"

...SUCCESS

make[2]: Entering directory '/home/msairam/nitrogen'

Turning "reltool.config" into a slim release

make[3]: Entering directory '/home/msairam/nitrogen'

==> rel (generate)

ERROR: generate failed while processing /home/msairam/nitrogen/rel: {'EXIT',

    {undef,

        [{reltool,start_server,

             [[{sys,

                   [{profile,development},

                    {excl_lib,otp_root},

                    {rel,"nitrogen","2.3.1",

                        [kernel,stdlib,sasl,crypto,runtime_tools,xmerl,

                         compiler,ssl,common_test,parsetools]},

                    {rel,"start_clean",[],[kernel,stdlib]},

                    {boot_rel,"nitrogen"},

                    {excl_sys_filters,
                        ["^bin/.*","^usr.*","^doc.*","^README$",

                         "^Install.ini$","^Install.exe$","^Uninstall.exe$",

                         "^COPYRIGHT$","^PR.template$"]},

                    {excl_archive_filters,[".*"]},

                    {incl_cond,include}]}]],

             []},

 {rebar_reltool,generate,2,[]},

         {rebar_core,run_modules,4,[]},

         {rebar_core,execute,6,[]},

         {rebar_core,maybe_execute,8,[]},

         {rebar_core,process_dir1,7,[]},

         {rebar_core,process_commands,2,[]},

         {rebar,main,1,[]}]}}

Makefile:312: recipe for target 'generate' failed

make[3]: *** [generate] Error 1

make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/msairam/nitrogen'

Makefile:328: recipe for target 'rel_inner_slim' failed

make[2]: *** [rel_inner_slim] Error 2

make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/msairam/nitrogen'

Makefile:190: recipe for target 'slim' failed

make[1]: *** [slim] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/msairam/nitrogen'

Makefile:150: recipe for target 'slim_yaws' failed

make: *** [slim_yaws] Error 2
```

New to erlang. Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: The GitHub page https://github.com/nitrogen/nitrogen#building-nitrogen-on-linux-and-osx shows that the installation instructions are here: http://nitrogenproject.com/doc/index.html#sec-3 Can you try them first? This fails because the function http://erlang.org/doc/man/reltool.html#start_server-1 is undefined, either the `reltool` application is not in the path or couldn't be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a problem with your Erlang installation -- the reltool application is probably missing.

One of the things that should be fixed in the Nitrogen docs is *how* to properly install Erlang. The current docs more-or-less assume Erlang is already installed.

The Erlang packages provided by Ubuntu/Debian are largely federated, meaning `apt-get install erlang` doesn't give you all of Erlang - there are a bunch of missing applications there.

Instead, I usually recommend downloading and installing the packages prepared by Erlang Solutions: https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html

Specifically, the `esl-erlang` package is *complete* erlang, while the `erlang` package is the federated package.  If you're new to Erlang, or not sure which to install, `esl-erlang` is the safest choice one to install, which will ensure you get *all* of erlang.

**NEW INSTRUCTIONS**

Install the packages as follows:

```
wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
```

**END NEW INSTRUCTIONS**

Either that, or installing Erlang from source using the typical `configure && make && make install` pattern. http://www.erlang.org/downloads

Once done, try re-running `make slim_yaws PROJECT=testproj` within Nitrogen.

Comment: I've modified my answer to include explicit instructions on installation. Specifically, installing the `esl-erlang` package is *complete* erlang, while the `erlang` package is merely a small subset of erlang.

Answer (score 0):

I installed erlang version 18.3 from https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html.   Similarly i downloaded the nitrogen  and used the instruction as given in  http://nitrogenproject.com/doc/index.html#sec-3.

For time being i am using the embed option and using nitrogen.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: So you've installed 18.3 from erlang solutions, and you continue to get the same error? What operating system?

Comment: So you have Ubuntu 16.06 installed. And you installed the packages from Erlang solutions.  If you run `erl` at the command line, and then run `reltool:module_info().`, what do you get?

Comment: iam getting exception error: undefined function reltool:module_info/0

Comment: This means that the reltool app is missing (and the errors are not a result of a path issue, or something like that, in the Makefile). Something about the installation is incomplete.

Comment: i downloaded the source code of 18.3 and  compiled. Now the reltool app is there. I am able to install nitrogen. Thanks for your help @chops.

Answer (score 0):

i have installed Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus).

Comment: You should probably refrain from posting your followup responses as separate "answers". Instead, reply to the questions. using the "Add a comment" link.

Comment: I removed the current erlang and installing from the source code downloaded from http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_18.3.tar.gz. I followed the instruction as given in http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html#Advanced-configuration-and-build-of-ErlangOTP_Building_Building-with-wxErlang. But when i check the test case $ERL_TOP/release/tests/test_server/index.html i am getting 3 failed error

tests.emulator_test.time_SUITE - Sat May 14 2016 19:32:42 14 3 0 (0/0) 0 test_server@passion CT Log Old Runs.

can somebody help me to sort out this?

Comment: That file should be telling you which test cases failed. It should be a clickable link with details.